# Friendly URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to transform the following url:

```
http://localhost/index.php?foo=bar&bar=foo
```

Into:

```
http://localhost/index/bar/foo
```

In other words I want to replace the page extension with a forward slash, then recursively rewrite one or more variables.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# to redirect the browser to friendly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?foo=([^&]+)&bar=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /index/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

# to internally rewrite friendly back to the proper resource
RewriteRule ^/?index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2 [L,QSA]
```